# SHA512 within Silverlight is not available, is there a managed library available?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, sha512

`SHA512Managed` is missing in Silverlight (for Windows Phone 7 CTP SDK), only upto SHA256 is available for use.  Does anyone know a .NET class that I could use that offers a self-contained C# or VB.net SHA512 implementation?

I need to use this for authentication to a HTTP web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **HashLib** from http://hashlib.codeplex.com/ will work fine. There are methods within `HashLib.HashFactory.HashCryptoNotBuildIn` that do not require `System.Crytography`.

Comment: I am wondering how can I use this library in Silverlight because the HasLih.dll cannot be imported...Also, I cannot compile the project for SilverLight...

Comment: You would need to just move over the code you need instead of importing the whole library.

Answer (score 1):

Mono has an implementation you could probably use, provided you are happy with the OS license.

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/SHA512Managed.cs

Comment: First line of code: `public class SHA512Managed : SHA512` Not a good start for an alternative?

Comment: code looks like a sha impl to me SHA512  I bet its just base abstract class

Comment: Yes. My question mark shouldn't have been there. I'm searching a SHA512 out-of-the-box algorithm for Windows Phone and saw these SHA512Managed and SHA256Managed still depend on SHA512 and SHA256.

Answer (score -1):

Silverlight does not contain the System.Security.Cryptogray namespace.  However, you could always port the open source BeeCrypt Cryptography Library (written in C), and use it directly in Silverlight.

http://www.koders.com/info.aspx?c=ProjectInfo&pid=VZ53QH5WTR5UV7LWXYVDKP7P3G

Comment: Sorry, I am asking for an existing .NET class.

Answer (score -1):

As there is no support for `SHA512`, we have to use our own or 3rd party implementations.
[(Check msdn here..)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/27475053-bcef-4d16-af95-d378a09be685/how-do-i-generate-sha512-hash-in-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop)

**Chilkat**'s implementation worked for me. It is very simple & straight-forward to use.
[Check it out here..](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/crypt_hash_algorithms.asp)

Comment: @Rob16299: I'm using it in my Windows Phone Silverlight app. Which type of application you are developing?